# Why half transitive graphs have even degree?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, symmetry

A graph is [half transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-transitive_graph) if it is both vertex and edge transitive, but not arc transitive.

> **Question:** Why is every half transitive graph of even degree?

(there is no trivial example)

The solution seems to be simple because it is stated as an elementary homework.

Comment: The relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-transitive_graph) says: _Every connected symmetric graph must be vertex-transitive and edge-transitive, and the converse is true for graphs of odd degree, so that half-transitive graphs of odd degree do not exist. However, there do exist half-transitive graphs of even degree._ There are references, like: __Bouwer, Z. "Vertex and Edge Transitive, But Not 1-Transitive Graphs." Canad. Math. Bull. 13, 231–237, 1970__ It also links to the smallest example, the [Holt graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holt_graph) (1976, 1981).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be half-transitive and $e\in E(G)$ an edge.
Choose an orientation of $e$.
Because $G$ is edge- but not arc-transitive, this induces a *unique* orientation on every other edge of $G$.
We obtain a directed graph $G'$ with $\mathrm{Aut}(G)=\mathrm{Aut}(G')$.

Now let us count the number $d_{\mathrm{out}}(i)$ of out-going edges and the number $d_{\mathrm{in}}(i)$ of in-going edges at a vertex $i\in V$.
Since $G$ is vertex-transitive, these numbers are the same for every vertex, so let's call them $d_{\mathrm{out}}$ and $d_{\mathrm{in}}$.

Because every edge has a head and a tail, in *every* directed graph holds

$$\sum_{i\in V} d_{\mathrm{out}}(i)=\sum_{i\in V} d_{\mathrm{in}}(i).$$

But the left side equals $|V| d_{\mathrm{out}}$, and the right side equals $|V| d_{\mathrm{in}}$.
Cancelling out $|V|$ yields that we have the same number of out-going edges as in-going edges at every vertex. Therefore the degree must be even.

By the way, this argument shows that *every* vertex-transitive directed graph has even degree.